# Code blocks wrap on new-answers-old-questions

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

If the code block in one of the answers contains a long string, then the content on the [page new-answers-old-questions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) does not fit into the visible area:

[image]

If you apply the styles [suggested](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641747/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1345937#comment2384537_1345937) by the [Qwertiy ♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy):

```css
.default-view-post-table { width: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 185px; }
.default-view-post-table > tbody, .default-view-post-table > tbody > tr { display: contents; }
.default-view-post-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child { width: unset !important; overflow: auto; }
```

then the page looks fine:

[image]